# Xcode 6 document availability issue

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 6, the document of some functions declares that the availability of the function is iOS 8 and later, but in fact that function exists before iOS 8 as well.

For example, the doc of `-[NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody]`in Xcode 6 is like this:[image]

However, in Xcode 5, it is like this:[image]

This confused me, as all I want to do is to use `setHTTPBody` and make sure it does not crash my app before iOS 8. In this case, although the doc of Xcode 6 says it is "iOS 8 only", in fact it is not, my time is wasted double checking its availability.

For some time, whenever I see some "iOS 8 only" functions like this in the document in Xcode 6, I still have to double check, and most of the time they exist before iOS 8. So how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: The problem is that iOS 8 replaced many setter/getter methods with a property. Even though the resulting functionality is identical, the actual use of a property is new as of iOS 8. Not sure what you can do but that is the reason.

Comment: BTW - this is an iOS 8 issue, not an Xcode 6 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation itself you can clearly see that:

**Prior to iOS 8:**

There is a custom setter for setting the `HTTPBody` property. The property itself was private.

```
- (void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data;
```

**In iOS 8:**

`HTTPBody` is a public property.

```
@property (copy) NSData *HTTPBody;
```

Comment: You're wrong, the documentation does not mention the `setHTTPBody:` method anywhere. Only the `@property` is documented and it's listed as iOS 8 and later. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableURLRequest/HTTPBody

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: That method is no longer available, since the property is there. Let me find the old documentation for that class.

Comment: @AbhiBekert He is not wrong. Look at the two screenshots you posted. Prior to IOS 8 there is a setter and getter method. In iOS 8 those were replaced with a property.

Comment: @rmaddy I didn't post any screenshots... I don't have Xcode 5 installed, which is where the OP got the screenshot from. In the latest version of Xcode and on developer.apple.com and in the *.h file, there is no documentation anywhere for the instance method.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Sorry, I thought you were the poster of the question. I didn't look well enough. That aside, of course the iOS 8 docs show the iOS 8 property. Docs from iOS 7 and earlier don't. They show the old methods. Hence, this answer isn't wrong.

Comment: @Midhun MP It is true (thx for the prompt reply), but does not change the fact that I still need to open my project in XCode 5 and double check if I can use `setHTTPBody` safely, since I'm not familiar with the API. Sometime ago I accidentally used `name` property of `NSOperation` to implement a feature in my app, which caused a lot of pain since it is truly an iOS 8 only property. This small issue is a little annoying isn't it?

Comment: @rmaddy Documentation for iOS 7 is not available anymore unless you install an old version of Xcode that's only available from a download location most people don't know exists, not to mention it requires gigabytes of disk space and is a productivity nightmare and might be buggy on Yosemite. This is definitely a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert How is it a bug? The methods were deprecated and a new property was added. The docs show, correctly, that the property was added in iOS 8. I agree it's misleading but technically it is correct.

Comment: @zannnennkunn: Yes, you are correct in that context. As mentioned by rmaddy in iOS 8 many custom getters and setters are replaced by public property.

Answer (score 2):

The complier generates slightly different binary code for properties, so these two lines of code are different:

```
request.HTTPBody = foo;
[request setHTTPBody:foo];
```

The differences are subtle, but I would use the latter if your app runs on iOS 7.

As for what you should do about it, file a bug with Apple: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ — be sure to select Documentation as the product you're reporting a bug on.

Comment: It is not a bug, as mentioned by @rmaddy, it's a misleading information. But overall it is correct. (They are specifically pointing to the property in the iOS 8 documentation).

Comment: @MidhunMP misleading information is a bug, there's an an entire section of radar and huge team of engineers at Apple devoted to fixing bugs in Xcode's documentation.

Comment: Then can you suggest how they should write the new property documentation in this context (For iOS 8) ?

Comment: @MidhunMP I don't know how they should fix it. Just describe the problem and let Apple figure out a solution.

Comment: @Abhi Beckert Thx for the advice, just did that (fire a bug report)